# How can I remove a document when the document is opened in Microsoft Word online 365?

Tags: office-365, delete, microsoft-word

How can I remove a document when the document is opened in Microsoft Word online 365?

E.g. in Google document I can do:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a document is opened in Microsoft Word online 365, there is currently no way to I delete the document. One has to go to OneDrive and delete it from there:

[image]